# Response from Google Cloud Platform to Django app

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-platform, python-requests, response

I created a simple Django app and tested in the local server and it was working fine. The app is expected to work like, whenever a post request is received to the corresponding view, the response should be an audio file . In the local server it is working as expected and the response header is showing "'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg'" but from the Google cloud I am not getting the audio file and the response header is showing the content type as "text/html".

---

Django view

```py
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.FILES['file']

        tmp = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, "Image", data.name)
        path = default_storage.save(tmp, ContentFile(data.read()))
        tmp_file = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, path)

        # ================ DATA PROCESSING =======================
        # Image can be acced in :: tmp_file

        # ================ DATA PROCESSING - END =======================
        fhandle = open("piZero/from_file.mp3", 'rb')  # audio output file name
        tmp = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, "Audio", "output.mp3")
        path = default_storage.save(tmp, ContentFile(fhandle.read()))
        audioFile = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, path)

        # Response build
        file_handle = open(audioFile, "rb")
        file = file_handle.read()
        file_handle.close()
        response = HttpResponse(file, content_type="audio/mpeg")
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=filename.mp3'
        return response


    else:
        return HttpResponse("GET")
```

---

app.yaml

: since I don't have any static files I haven't run the collect static. In the actual program this audio file will be created from the program. So I don't know whether to put this as static or not.

```yaml
# [START django_app]
runtime: python38
handlers:
# This configures Google App Engine to serve the files in the app's
# static directory.
- url: /static
  static_dir: static/
# This handler routes all requests not caught above to the main app.
# It is required when static routes are defined, but can be omitted
# (along with the entire handlers section) when there are no static
# files defined.
- url: /.*
  script: auto
# [END django_app]
```

---

settings.py :: last part

```py
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'Media')
```

---

program connecting to the Django :: post to Django server

```py
    myfiles = {'file': open(file_name, 'rb')}

    myobj = {'somekey': 'somevalue'}
    
    x = requests.post(url, data=myobj, files=myfiles)

    print(x.headers)
    print(x.content)

    with open("dummy1.mp3", 'wb') as filehandle:
        for chunk in x.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
            filehandle.write(chunk)
```

---

Is there any other configuration to be done in the google cloud platform for serving it properly . I am not using the database / Model in my view.

---

1. Please explain why it is working as expected in the local server but not in the google cloud platform
2. What to be done in the google cloud platform to work it as expected.

The response can be viewed [here](https://dpaste.com/8D4JS3BTZ).

Comment: Are you sure you deployed the correct code, it seems to me that this should work as intended. Could you check you appengine source code against the code posted here? Also, in your view you create a `response` variable, set the content disposition header, but then you return a new response object. I don't think that's what you meant to do right?

Comment: Thanks , I have corrected the response as `# Response build
        file_handle = open(audioFile, "rb")
        file = file_handle.read()
        file_handle.close()
        response = HttpResponse(file, content_type="audio/mpeg")
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=filename.mp3'
        return response` But still the same result .@NicoGriffioen

Comment: If the response type is `text/html`, what's in the body of the response? Can you show the output of `curl`-ing the endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

I tried replicating your code [here](https://repl.it/repls/InfatuatedMinorFormula) , and as others mentioned everything works fine. One possibility though is the html returned 403 (forbidden) due to failed CSRF verification. Something like

```
<h1>Forbidden <span>(403)</span></h1>
<p>CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.</p>
```

As @dustin-ingram mentioned if you can post the response output, it would have been easier to debug.

**UPDATE 1:**
There seems to be no issues with the provided code (I tested with the GCP). Can you check whether you are passing correct dict for the `files` in the `request.post` (i.e. `myfiles` should have a key `file`). The error you have pasted suggest that "file" key is missing in FILES.

PS: This should have been a comment, but I don't have enough reputation points. Hope that's ok.